# How to break line before 5 chars number

Tags: php, regex

I want to break line before all 5 chars numbers. How can I do that ?
what I got:

```
$line[1] = preg_replace('[0-9]{5}', '\r\n\1',$line[1]);
```

but it seems to don't work.Does anyone know how can I do that ?
here is my string example:

```
Zum Sonnenhügel 19 37688 Beverungen
```

so from this I want to do this:

```
Zum Sonnenhügel 19
37688 Beverungen
```

I have google doc spreadsheet with a column of addresses like this. but I can not to change it there, so I downloaded it as csv and i want to edit it in php

the error I'm getting:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '{' in ...\Command\EditCsvCommand.php line 54
```

Comment: If you will be performing this operation on multiple strings, it would help to know if the format of this string is consistent with every string. IE does every string have 2 digits a space then 5 digits a space and a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to speicfy regular expression delimiter, capturing group to use backreference.

```
$line[1] = preg_replace('/([0-9]{5})/', "\r\n\1", $line[1]);
```

In addition to that Use double quote to make `\r\n` to be interpreted correctly.

I used `/`, but you can choose other characters.

**UPDATE**

As Blackhole commented, if you use `$0` (the text matched), you don't need to use capturing group:

```
$line[1] = preg_replace('/[0-9]{5}/', "\r\n$0", $line[1]);
```

Comment: @Blackhole, Thank you for your comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$1` instead of `\1`:

```
$line[1] = preg_replace('/([0-9]{5})/', "\r\n$1", $line[1]);
```

Comment: error im getting: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '{'

Comment: nice it works but the result is:
`Zum Sonnenhügel 19 \r\n Beverungen`

Comment: Okay, you need to wrap it in `"`. Check updated answer.

Comment: Should use capturing group. Otherwise, 5 digits will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Also can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to insert `"\r\n"` at the desired position:

```
$line[1] = preg_replace('/(?=\b\d{5}\b)/', "\r\n", $line[1]);
```

Added `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to separate the `\d` part better.

See [example on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/lG3aV6/2)

Comment: This is the smartest answer.